# While using PyAudio to generate tones why do I get clicks between them?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyaudio

Title explains what the problem is. I have no idea how to fix this. The clicking is between each of the tones played. I also sounds like a pop to some people.

```
import math
import pyaudio
import sys

PyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio


def playTone(rate,wave,time,channel):
  data = ''.join([chr(int(math.sin(x/((rate/wave)/math.pi))*127+128)) for x in xrange(rate)])
  p = PyAudio()

  stream = p.open(format =
    p.get_format_from_width(1),
    channels = channel,
    rate = rate,
    output = True)
  for DISCARD in xrange(int(time)):
      stream.write(data)
  #stream.stop_stream()
  #stream.close()
  #p.terminate()


'''
playTone(88000,400,1,2)
playTone(88000,500,1,1)
playTone(88000,600,1,2)
playTone(88000,700,1,2)
'''

def scale(noteNumber):
  counter = 100
  while noteNumber*100 > counter:
    playTone(88000,100+counter,1,2)
    counter += 100

scale(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gap between building `data = ''.join([...` and playing `stream.write(data)`.
The gap makes click sound.

To find out, try dump the `data` and play it as 88000Hz, 8bit and 2ch raw data.

Simple solution is to generate all signal before playing.

Or, use different threads to generate and play sound.